# How to set the canvas size in Firemonkeys TPathData?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is there any way to define in TPathData the size of the canvas to draw on? I can't find any such property and TPath seems to draw the top left corner value and the bottom right corner value from the vectors themselves. If I first Move (0,0) followed by Move(W,H) it works, but seems a bit strange to solve this problem with such a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  TPathData does not have a canvas.  You can use TPathData to draw on a canvas that belongs to a control, in which case the size of the canvas is defined by the size of the control.

Comment: It's the only way I found too